# How to trigger creation of savefile

Tags: c, libretro

I'm trying to create a libretro core. It will be a standalone game, so I'm setting `RETRO_ENVIRONMENT_SET_SUPPORT_NO_GAME` to `true`. The [documentation](https://github.com/libretro/libretro-common/blob/master/include/libretro.h#L791) suggests that `retro_get_memory_*` can be used to have data saved without needing to explicitly query `RETRO_ENVIRONMENT_GET_SAVE_DIRECTORY`:

> The save directory should be used to
>   store SRAM, memory cards, high scores, etc, if the libretro core
>   cannot use the regular memory interface (retro_get_memory_data()).

**How should the core trigger the saving of data using this interface? Or am I misunderstanding the documentation?**

I would expect the frontend to call `retro_get_memory_{data,size}`, read from the exposed buffer when stopping the core, persist the data to disk, and write it back to the exposed buffer the next time the core starts. Instead I observe:

- If I don't provide a content file, the frontend never calls `retro_get_memory_{data,size}`.
- If I provide a content file (which is unused), the frontend calls `retro_get_memory_{data,size}` after `retro_load_game` but doesn't write to disk.

---

Note that this question is about *save files* (automatically persisted data, usually capturing the player's progress), not *save states* (snapshots of the game state triggered by the user) which are implemented by the `*serialize*` methods.

---

Here is a simple example to reproduce the issue (based on [this sample](https://github.com/libretro/libretro-samples/blob/master/video/software/rendering/libretro-test.c)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "libretro.h"

static unsigned char c = 0;

void* retro_get_memory_data(unsigned id) {
  fprintf(stderr, "retro_get_memory_data(%d)\n", id);
  return (id == RETRO_MEMORY_SAVE_RAM) ? &c : NULL;
}

size_t retro_get_memory_size(unsigned id) {
  fprintf(stderr, "retro_get_memory_size(%d)\n", id);
  return (id == RETRO_MEMORY_SAVE_RAM) ? 1 : 0;
}

#define WIDTH 320
#define HEIGHT 240

static uint32_t* frame_buf;

void retro_init(void) { frame_buf = calloc(WIDTH * HEIGHT, sizeof(uint32_t)); }

void retro_deinit(void) {
  free(frame_buf);
  frame_buf = NULL;
}

unsigned retro_api_version(void) { return RETRO_API_VERSION; }

void retro_get_system_info(struct retro_system_info* info) {
  memset(info, 0, sizeof(*info));
  info->library_name = "SaveTest";
  info->library_version = "v1";
  info->need_fullpath = false;
  info->valid_extensions = NULL;  // Anything is fine, we don't care.
}

static retro_video_refresh_t video_cb;
static retro_environment_t environ_cb;
static retro_input_poll_t input_poll_cb;
static retro_input_state_t input_state_cb;

void retro_set_input_poll(retro_input_poll_t cb) { input_poll_cb = cb; }
void retro_set_input_state(retro_input_state_t cb) { input_state_cb = cb; }
void retro_set_video_refresh(retro_video_refresh_t cb) { video_cb = cb; }
void retro_set_environment(retro_environment_t cb) {
  environ_cb = cb;
  bool no_content = true;
  cb(RETRO_ENVIRONMENT_SET_SUPPORT_NO_GAME, &no_content);
}

void retro_get_system_av_info(struct retro_system_av_info* info) {
  float aspect = (float)WIDTH / HEIGHT;

  info->timing = (struct retro_system_timing){
      .fps = 60.0,
      .sample_rate = 0.0,
  };

  info->geometry = (struct retro_game_geometry){
      .base_width = WIDTH,
      .base_height = HEIGHT,
      .max_width = WIDTH,
      .max_height = HEIGHT,
      .aspect_ratio = aspect,
  };
}

unsigned retro_get_region(void) { return RETRO_REGION_NTSC; }

bool retro_load_game(const struct retro_game_info* info) {
  enum retro_pixel_format fmt = RETRO_PIXEL_FORMAT_XRGB8888;
  if (!environ_cb(RETRO_ENVIRONMENT_SET_PIXEL_FORMAT, &fmt)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "XRGB8888 is not supported.\n");
    return false;
  }
  (void)info;
  return true;
}

bool button(unsigned id) {
  return input_state_cb(0, RETRO_DEVICE_JOYPAD, 0, id);
}

void retro_run(void) {
  input_poll_cb();
  if (button(RETRO_DEVICE_ID_JOYPAD_LEFT) && c > 0) --c;
  if (button(RETRO_DEVICE_ID_JOYPAD_RIGHT) && c < 255) ++c;
  uint32_t color = (255 - c) | (c << 8);
  uint32_t* buf = frame_buf;
  for (unsigned i = WIDTH * HEIGHT; i > 0; --i) {
    *buf = color;
    ++buf;
  }
  video_cb(frame_buf, WIDTH, HEIGHT, WIDTH * sizeof(uint32_t));
}

void retro_unload_game(void) {}

size_t retro_serialize_size(void) { return 1; }
bool retro_serialize(void* data, size_t size) {
  fprintf(stderr, "serialize(%p, %lu) <= %u\n", data, size, c);
  *(char*)data = c;
  return true;
}
bool retro_unserialize(const void* data, size_t size) {
  c = *(char*)data;
  fprintf(stderr, "unserialize(%p, %lu) => %u\n", data, size, c);
  return true;
}

void retro_set_controller_port_device(unsigned port, unsigned device) {}
void retro_set_audio_sample(retro_audio_sample_t cb) {}
void retro_set_audio_sample_batch(retro_audio_sample_batch_t cb) {}
void retro_reset(void) {}
bool retro_load_game_special(unsigned type, const struct retro_game_info* info,
                             size_t num) {
  return false;
}
void retro_cheat_reset(void) {}
void retro_cheat_set(unsigned index, bool enabled, const char* code) {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is undocumented but intended that auto save does not trigger for a core without content.

Moreover auto save was not triggering for cores which had content but could support no content. This was unintended and recently fixed.

Reference: https://github.com/libretro/RetroArch/issues/9300